# how to get only url parameters when send ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

i have a url like http://mydomain.com/wp_bankers/wp-admin/themes.php?page=theme_page_options=general_settings&subsection=footer_settings&ajax=true

now i want to get only parameter. but when request send in div current page show.

```
jQuery('#sah_form a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    href = ( href.indexOf('ajax=true') > 0 ) ? href : href + '&ajax=true';
     jQuery.get(href, function (data) {
                jQuery('div#href').html(data);
      });

});
});

echo '<div id="href">';                         
echo '<b>'.$_GET['subsection'].'</b>';                                                  
echo '</div>';
```

i need some help

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's the problem? You are not getting the value of `$_GET['subsection']` ?

Comment: basically i want only parameters when request send

Comment: Tejas Jayasheel is right, try to be clearer explaining what you want to do... And consider separating server side from client side scripting more carefully... :-)